# Applescript to capture window

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create an applescript to capture a window. The keyboard shortcut is cmd+shift+4 then space. I am not able to use this in applescript.

My code :

```
tell application "system events"
keystroke "21, 49" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

It doesnt work. The problem with the scrip it using space bar. I need to hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> & <kbd>4</kbd> and then press <kbd>space</kbd> bar.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke (ASCII character 36) using {command down}
    delay 1
    keystroke space
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

This Applescript might work better for you rather than using GUI scripting
it uses the screen capture command line. for more info look at the [screencapture Man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html)

```
set fileName to do shell script "date \"+Screen Shot  %Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S.png\""
tell application "System Events" to set thePath to POSIX path of desktop folder
do shell script "screencapture  -W " & "\"" & thePath & "/" & fileName & "\""
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get to that point then use this:
tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using {shift down, command down}
    delay 0.1
    key code 49
end tell